# Will Indians transiting via Doha (Hamad International Airport) to USA be subjected to 10 day mandatory quarantine?

Tags: covid-19, qatar-airways, quarantine

I was going through the list of requirements for travelers to Doha on their website.

It said people from COVID countries like India, Pakistan etc were subjected to 10 days mandatory quarantine.

The text is unclear about whether it applies only to arrivals with Qatar as their final destination.

It seems to imply passengers transiting via Doha (who are Indians from India) don't have to be subject to quarantine.

I need some help in figuring this out. I have reached out to Qatar via Twitter and am still waiting to get clarification on the requirements.

This is what their travel restriction page says about Indians and those from red list countries:

https://www.qatarairwaysholidays.com/qa-en/welcome-home-7-night-booking/overview

> Travelers from Bangladesh, India, Nepal, Pakistan, Philippines, Sri Lanka and Vietnam:
> Exemptions from quarantine policy for vaccinated individuals does not apply.
> The following measures are implemented for travelers coming from Bangladesh, India, Nepal, Pakistan, Sri Lanka, Philippines and Vietnam whether they are traveling through direct flight or via other countries (transit), which include:
> All passengers whose original flight is from the said countries are subject to mandatory COVID-19 PCR Test done 48 hours before departure from the testing centers approved by their local health authority. Knowing that no one can board the flight to Qatar without a valid Negative PCR certificate.
>
>  All passengers transiting through Qatar must have the mandatory pre-travel PCR test as mentioned in point 1, and in case they require another PCR test for their onward destination, they can have it at Hamad International Airport on a standard fee of QAR 300/- per test.​​

Comment: Seems like you already answered yourself. Generally speaking, air transit doesn't usually change rules one way or another. There are few exceptions, of course.

Comment: Note though that there are entry requirements for the US too. From [the website of the US Embassy in India](https://in.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information/) (more info on that page): *" Effective May 4, the entry into the United States of certain nonimmigrant travelers who have been physically present in India is suspended by Presidential Proclamation."*

Comment: Yes, I have a special visa to enter the US. It is one of the exempted categories from the Presidential Proclamation. Namely that of an F-1 student, the rest of my family are Permanent Residents of USA so, they too are exempted from the Presidential Proclamation.

Answer (score 7):

I got in touch with the department responsible for the 10 day quarantine hotel bookings, which was listed in the official Qatar website:

https://www.qatarairwaysholidays.com/qa-en/offers/welcome-home-packages/

I emailed them,  I specifically highlighted I was an Indian transiting via Doha. To make super sure, they understood my profile, this was the reply I got.

> Dear Customer,
>
> Greetings from Discover Qatar,
>
> Please be advised if you are only transit in Doha you don't need a
> hotel quarantine package, as you don't leave the airport. Only the
> customers entering the state of Qatar, are required to quarantine for
> 10 days.
>
> Wish you a safe journey!

This information is current at least for June 26th from them. I am hoping it will remain the same, unless something else comes up in the future.